# Eclipse Blackberry webworks debuging is not supported in 6.0.0.0 simulators

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-webworks

I'm new to phonegap blackberry mobile applications. I installed Eclipse 3.6 with blackberry webworks plugin. When I try to execute my sample program in debug mode it shows

```
Debugging is not supported in 6.0.0 simulators. The session will be launched in run mode.
```

How do I view `console.log()` in the eclipse console? How do I add more simulators in eclipse blackberry webworks plugin IDE? And how do I run Blackberry OS 7.1 version simulators?

Comment: Do you have any reasons to make your app for Blackberry OS 6&7 instead of Blackberry 10?

Comment: Thanks for your reply poiuytrez. I don't know the difference on BBOS versions. I have a doubt If I develop app for Blackberry 10 that will work on lower version also?.

Answer (score 0):

The Blackberry Webworks plugin for Eclipse is not supported anymore. I would recommend to follow the steps in the [Blackberry Phonegap getting started guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20BlackBerry).

Answer (score 0):

WebWorks debugging on BBOS is a complicated story. On BBOS 5.0 you can debug using eclipse, on 6.0 there is no debugging protocol and 7.0+ you can use remote webinspector.